# negative boolean expressions and eager boolean OR

Tags: javascript, naming, boolean

I come across these kinds of expressions and I have hard time reading it. 
How do you read it properly to see if it is the right logic when debugging.

```
if (!(userLoggedIn || isAdmin)) {
    console.log('User does not have rights');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly expand the shorthand

```
if (! (userLoggedIn = true  || isAdmin = true ))
```

Then replace logical operators with words

```
if (not (userLoggedIn = true or isAdmin= true))
```

Then translate

```
If the user is not either logged in or admin
{
    //do something
}
```

Once you've thought about it like this the first time, the original becomes pretty trivial to read in one go - suddenly it clearly states 'if the user is not either logged in or admin' without any need to translate, this is also the beauty of good Boolean variable names as seen in this example

```
if (!(userLoggedIn || isAdmin))
```

Comment: Two small points: one, "either" usually means not both, but if userLoggedIn and isAdmin are true, the result will be false. Two, sometimes but not always it's useful to break it down to !userLoggedIn && !isAdmin

Comment: Alternate is  (in you head ) remove the !, add an empty body and insert an else. 
if ( (userLoggedIn || isAdmin )) {} else { do something ....}

Comment: I find it easy to explain, with the use of `or` in English. 'If the user is not logged in or admin', which makes sense in English; even if mathematically it's different.

Comment: Raptor good point but I tend to assume that the reader understands the logical difference between or and xor, at least enough to understand the context of "either" - Rob's comment would avoid that, and could be a good alternative if the person has less understanding of the logical operators. In this case it seemed that the user understood the individual operators. @mattnz that's very true, but **if(condition) /*nothing*/ else logic** should, in my opinion, be avoided

Comment: I don't understand why people write "userLoggedIn == true".  To me, usedLoggedIn read like "user is logged in".  Adding "== true" forces you to think of userLoggedIn as a value and not a predicate.

Comment: To me it's more about the fact that if you explicitly state that its true, you can then remove the 'not' by swapping it to false. I would only ever do this for explanation purpose, though - I write my actual code in the if( predicate ) style. I only added it here to show the reader that the value is indeed true

Answer (score 2):

Generally, !(a || b) => (!a && !b),

so !(userLoggedIn || isAdmin) => !userLoggedIn && !isAdmin,

which is much clearer to me, probably due to the lack of parentheses.

Comment: This is [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Answer (score 0):

To me the underlying logic is:

`userLoggedIn || isAdmin` reads "user must be logged in or in admin mode".

`if(!...)` reads "If it is not the case, then ...".

Taken together your code means "if it is not the case that the user is logged in or is in admin mode, then print the error message".

This makes me wonder if you didn't mean that the user must be logged in and have admin rights.  In that case, you should replace `||` by `&&`.